# Excess-N to 2's complement

Tags: assembly, binary, intel, twos-complement

Could someone please explain how to do this? It's not homework.

Could someone please explain to me how to do this?

```
Show that if N is chosen to be equal to 2^(m-1) where m is the number of bits
in the representation, then an Excess N representation will be the same as a 2's
Complement representation but with the sign bit inverted. Hint - transform the
summation formula for Excess-N numbers to the summation formula for 2's Comp
numbers.
```

First of all, how do I transform the summation formula for excess-N numbers to the formula for 2's Complement numbers? Secondly, how exactly am I supposed to prove that?

Comment: If that's not homework, then what is it?  And what language are you using?

Comment: Unless I severly misunderstood, this is math, not programming. Maybe try another StackExchange site? There's one for math, and one for computer science. That said, have you actually grabbed a pencil and tried to do it, just to see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers in a computer are stored as *m* bits which hold a number in the range [0..(2^m)-1] -- positive (unsigned) numbers.  So to represent negative numbers, you need to encode the negative numbers into this space somehow.  There are number of ways of doing that, and the terms **Sign-Magnitude**, **Twos-complement**, **Ones-Complement** and **Excess-N** all refer to different way of doing that.

**Excess N** notation means that you deal with negative numbers by adding the constant N to all numbers, so that you only ever have positive numbers to deal with.  So a value of 0 represents -N, a value of 1, represents -N+1, etc.  A value of N represents 0.

Now, I'm not sure what book you are referring to, but a **Summation Formula** will usually refer to a way of computing a value by summing a bunch of terms.  In the context of numeric representations, it usually assigns a 'value' to each bit, such that the sum of the value for the set bits gives you the number that is encoded.  When you do this for **Twos-complement**, you end up with one formula, and when you do it for **Excess-N** you end up with a slightly different formula, but you should be able to see/show the equivalence in your quoted question.

Answer (score 0):

I whish MathJax worked in StackOverflow. I'll just have to wrangle my way through this without it.

N = λ<sub>1</sub>( - 2^(L - 1)) + SUM(from n=2, to n=L)[λ<sub>n</sub>(2^(L - n)] is the 2's compliment expansion of N.

Here λ<sub>n</sub> E {0, 1} (bits); n in [1, L]; n E Z.

L = length of bits in N. (The question has L = m).

N<sub>max</sub> is thus SUM(from n=2, to n=L)[2^(L - n)]

N<sub>max</sub> = (2^(L - 1)) - 1  (simplified form)

So, the question is incorrect since you can't even represent an N = 2^(L - 1) in 2's compliment if the length of bits is L.

We can choose a more appropriate value for N, say N = N<sub>max</sub>.

Then λ<sub>n</sub> = { 0 for n = 1; 1 for n in [2, L] }; n E Z

So, the 2's compliment binary representation of N is (0,1,1,...1)<sub>b</sub> with L bits.

N = N<sub>E</sub> - E where N<sub>E</sub> is the Excess-N version of N and E is the Excess.

We know that E = 2^(L - 1). [Excess-N Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_binary)

N<sub>E</sub> = SUM(from n=1, to n=L)[α<sub>n</sub>(2^(L - n))] is the powers-of-2 expansion of N<sub>E</sub>.

Here, α<sub>n</sub> E {0, 1} (bits); n in [1, L]; n E Z

N = N<sub>E</sub> - E

N<sub>E</sub> = N + E

N<sub>E</sub> = N + 2^(L - 1)

N<sub>E</sub> = N<sub>max</sub> + 2^(L - 1)

N<sub>E</sub> = ((2^(L - 1)) - 1) + 2^(L - 1)

N<sub>E</sub> = SUM(from n=2, to n=L)[2^(L - n)] + 2^(L - 1)

N<sub>E</sub> = SUM(from n=1, to n=L)[2^(L - n)]

Next, we substitute the expansion of N<sub>E</sub>:

N<sub>E</sub> = SUM(from n=1, to n=L)[2^(L - n)]

SUM(from n=1, to n=L)[α<sub>n</sub>(2^(L - n))] = SUM(from n=1, to n=L)[2^(L - n)]

Which implies that α<sub>n</sub> = 1 for n in [1, L]; n E Z

So, the Excess-N binary representation of N is (1,1,1,...1)<sub>b</sub> with L bits.

Comparing the two representations, we can see that simply flipping the MSB in one notation produces the other.